# c# Left-shift operator << as the «for loop» «iterator»

Tags: c#, for-loop, bit-shift

I need to iterate through every bit of a byte. There are many ways to do it but my curiosity got piqued when trying to use a for loop with the "shift-left" operator as the iterator. This is what I would like to do.

```
for (byte i = 0x01; i <= 0x80; i << 1)
{
    value = value ^ i;
}
```

In this situation how could I use the shift-left operator (i << 1) for iteration?
In a typical for loop, you would have (int i=0; i < 10; i++) the iterator being i++ for incrementing by one.

Comment: Use the `<<= ` compound assignment operator, or simply type `i = i << 1`

Comment: Thx Emanuel..... Amazing what a single "=" sign can do.

Comment: Note that your for loop will never end, as 0x80 << 1 is 0x00 again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [compound assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#compound-assignment) form of the operator like `i <<= 1`. Or you can simply use `i = i << 1`.